# How should we make this VR/360 app?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, virtual-reality, 360-degrees

I'm Vincent, a French student. For a school project, my group and I are looking to make a 360 app on iOS. The idea is that the user will use the app with a cardboard, and live a 360 experience. Noone in my group never did this, so here I am, to get so good advices on which techs should we use to make our project live.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL38c.jpg (Illustration of the user using the app)

We find out that ArKit and Unity using the Google SDK VR are the two main techs to make what we want to, but the thing is that we're a little scared about choosing the wrong one. ArKit seems fine, but this is in 3D. We're more looking to project 2D image around the image and he can move the head to navigate between them. Unity, on its side, seems too much, and I not sure that the scripting / animating render well.

So what do you guys think ? ArKit ? Unity ? Maybe another thing ? I surely forget something, so please ask for more details :). Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need Unity+GoogleVR plugin for that,
ARKit/Vuforia is not needed, since you are not doing Augmented Reality.

For the panoramic image:
Use Equirectangular images, can assign it as a cubemap in unity,
or use shader Skybox/Panoramic (which support 360 or 180 degree image types)

Moving between other images:
GoogleVR has example scene on how to click objects,
then its just a matter of loading new panorama image there.

You can also play 360 videos on that panorama sphere,
using unity video player or some of the video player from asset store (they can handle youtube url parsing for you)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You should use Unity. It's easy to get started and you can essentially target all major platforms.

Long answer: Working with ARKit or ARCore ususally involves using Unity or some other engine. Using the SDKs directly is just a lot more work, and Unity is easy (and free!) to use. If you want to target cross platform development (mobile and PC) use Unity with Vuforia. Recent versions of Unity have Vuforia built it, so it should be very easy to get started. There should be a lot of documentation to get you started already (like [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/xr)).

Another path you might consider would be making it as an web app (HTML + JavaScript) using [aframe](https://aframe.io/). aframe is still fairly new tech but quite powerful already. It's mostly limited by browser support, and of course, doesn't have as much documentation as Unity or as many assets / plugins.